# I can't update multiple records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

So the sql code looks like this:

```
UPDATE 
    tbl1 
SET 
    LastModifiedDate = GETDATE(), 
    col1 = 'Closed', 
    LastModifiedBy = 'usr' 
WHERE 
    col2 = 'xxx' 
AND 
    col1 NOT LIKE '%Closed%' 
AND 
    DATEDIFF(day, DateTimeOfInsert, GETDATE()) > 30
AND 
col3 NOT IN 
    (SELECT 
         col3
     FROM 
         tbl1 
     WHERE 
         col2 = 'xxx' 
     AND 
         DATEDIFF(day, DateTimeOfInsert, GETDATE()) < 30)
```

Basically I want to close all records where col1 is 'xxx', which are not yet closed and which are older than 30 days and there is no similar record within the last 30 days.
This is what I get:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. The statement has been terminated.

I truly believe this trigger is causing the issue:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_tbl1_closeAction
ON tbl1
AFTER UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    If (SELECT col1 FROM INSERTED) NOT LIKE '%Close%'
      Begin
          Return
      End
    INSERT INTO tbl2
        (tbl_1_ID, col4, usr)
        select i.ID, '10', tu.id
        from inserted i
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl3 tu ON tu.usr=i.LastModifiedBy;  
    END
```

Comment: You have too strange `col3 NOT IN` subquery, i can't figure out why it's so

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your query? Could you provide us with some sample data to work with?

Comment: @FSou1 The reason for that part is to check whether there is a record newer than 30 days.

Comment: @wewesthemenace Well I can try, but does it matter? I mean it's true that it returns multiple values, but that is the point.

Comment: I've just executed your query, my result: `(0 row(s) affected)`. Could you provide your question with input data?

Comment: Is there an update trigger on `tbl1`?

Comment: @fishmong3r, yup. I agree it does not matter. Is there any trigger on `tbl1`?

Comment: Yes there are multiple triggers. Is that affects update?

Comment: @fishmong3r, yup. Check your triggers, one of those are causing the errors.

Comment: Added the trigger to the question. This trigger adds a so called 'log' entry to tbl2 if col1 in tbl1 is closed after update.

Comment: And it is working perfectly in case I close on single record in `tbl1`.

Comment: Yes, that trigger is broken. Although the bottom half correctly deals with `inserted` as a table, the `IF` check is assuming that `inserted` contains exactly one row.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah, like I said it works in case one record is being modified. How can I fix this to work regardless of the number of records modified?

Comment: Basically write the trigger(s) so that the Inserted and Deleted tables are assumed to contain any number of rows, instead of exactly 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trigger you've shown is indeed broken. Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_tbl1_closeAction
ON tbl1
AFTER UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO tbl2
        (tbl_1_ID, col4, usr)
        select i.ID, '10', tu.id
        from inserted i
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl3 tu ON tu.usr=i.LastModifiedBy
        WHERE i.col1 LIKE '%Close%';  
    END
```

Is probably what was intended (since `inserted` can contain multiple rows, *some* of which may be like `Close` and others not - so we move the filter down into a `WHERE` clause).

Comment: I honestly doubt I could figure it by myself.... I really appreciate your help. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Datediff is a subquery. In your case, it is probably returning more than one value (more than one record). Moreover, it is probably returning one value for each day or DateTimeOfInsert you have (perhaps both, I am unfamiliar with your schema, of course).

As the error states, you cannot use '<' on a subquery that returned more than one value.

Comment: That won't solve my issue. The same subquery works perfectly on a simple query (which is not update). So do you have any solutions how to achieve what I need?

Comment: Make Datediff into a subquery and filter according to its' value (something like Select id, Datediff AS 'x' WHERE x < 30)

Comment: Datediff is not a subquery, it is a scalar function. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: You're right. My phrasing was wrong. What I meant to say was that it acts as subquery since it receives several records, as thus while expected as scalar behaves as a subquery and its' result cannot have '<' operator applied to it. Thanks for you comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
If (SELECT col1 FROM INSERTED) NOT LIKE '%Close%'
```

`SELECT col1 FROM INSERTED` returns more then 1 row here when multiple update. If update packet should only update to status `closed` in `all or none` way then:

```
ALTER TRIGGER trg_tbl1_closeAction ON tbl1
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                    FROM    INSERTED
                    WHERE   col1 NOT LIKE '%Close%' )
            BEGIN
                RETURN
            END
        INSERT  INTO tbl2
                ( tbl_1_ID ,
                  col4 ,
                  usr
                )
                SELECT  i.ID ,
                        '10' ,
                        tu.id
                FROM    inserted i
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl3 tu ON tu.usr = i.LastModifiedBy;  
    END
```

Comment: The problem with this approach (or at least, I've assumed it's a problem) is that it takes a binary approach to all of the rows in `inserted`. If one of them matches the criteria in the `If exists(` check, they're all treated one way. If *none* of them match, then they're all treated the different way.